# CAS authentification with front end Angular

Tags: angular, cas

I have to create a CAS authentification for my Angular app (front) and PHP/Symfony (backend).

I tried to do it with the front by using http.get(cas_url) but when I try to validate my token, the CORS would not allow me to go further.

Since I cannot change the CORS settings of the server, I have to do it an another way.

So I tried using phpCAS and it works fine alone on an apache server but how can I put it together with my front with a specific url or action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped my compiled front-end index.html inside a `index.php` (include) and used [phpCAS](https://github.com/apereo/phpCAS) which does everything.

Then once the front is loaded, I call the function `phpCAS::getUser()` in onInit(), then do my authentification by looking for the user in the database.